# Emacs: Write buffer to new file, but keep this file open

Tags: file, emacs, duplicates, buffer

I want to do the following in Emacs: Save the current buffer to a new file, but also keep the current file open.
When I do C-x C-w then current buffer gets replaced, but I want to keep open both buffer. Is this possible without reopening the original file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built in, but it's easy enough to write:

```
(defun my-clone-and-open-file (filename)
  "Clone the current buffer writing it into FILENAME and open it"
  (interactive "FClone to file: ")
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (write-region (point-min) (point-max) filename nil nil nil 'confirm))
  (find-file-noselect filename))
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a snippet I've had for a while to do just this

```
;;;======================================================================
;;; provide save-as functionality without renaming the current buffer
(defun save-as (new-filename)
  (interactive "FFilename:")
  (write-region (point-min) (point-max) new-filename)
  (find-file-noselect new-filename))
```

Comment: Nope, this does not what I want. I want to have both files open. [Nonetheless a nice snippet, will add this to my .emacs, too]

Comment: I noticed that earlier, so I modified the post to use the find-file-noselect function. Both buffers remain loaded, but the original buffer still has the focus. If you want both visible at once, use find-file-other-window instead

Comment: Haha, I was too fast with my comment. Thanks!

Comment: Caveat: this snippet will overwrite existing files without warning.

Answer (score 5):

I found it helpful to combine Scott's and Chris's answers above. The user can call save-as and then answer "y" or "n" when prompted whether to switch to the new file. (Alternatively, the user can select the desired functionality via the function name save-as-and-switch or save-as-but-do-not-switch, but this requires more keystrokes. Those names are still available for being called by other functions in the future, however.)

```
;; based on scottfrazer's code
(defun save-as-and-switch (filename)
  "Clone the current buffer and switch to the clone"
  (interactive "FCopy and switch to file: ")
  (save-restriction
    (widen)
    (write-region (point-min) (point-max) filename nil nil nil 'confirm))
  (find-file filename))

;; based on Chris McMahan's code
(defun save-as-but-do-not-switch (filename)
  "Clone the current buffer but don't switch to the clone"
  (interactive "FCopy (without switching) to file:")
  (write-region (point-min) (point-max) filename)
  (find-file-noselect filename))

;; My own function for combining the two above.
(defun save-as (filename)
  "Prompt user whether to switch to the clone."
  (interactive "FCopy to file: ")
  (if (y-or-n-p "Switch to new file?")
    (save-as-and-switch filename)
    (save-as-but-do-not-switch filename)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
C-x h
```

selects all the buffer, then

```
M-x write-region
```

writes the region (whole buffer in this example) to another file.

Edit: this function does what you need

```
(defun write-and-open ( filename )
  (interactive "GClone to file:")
  (progn
    (write-region (point-min) (point-max) filename )
      (find-file filename  ))
      )
```

It's a bit crude, but modify to your will.

The interactive code 'G' prompts for a filename which goes into the 'filename' argument.

Drop this into your .emacs and call with M-x write-and-open (or define a key sequence).

Comment: Oops! this doesn't keep the new file open as you requested.

Comment: Yeah, that is my main problem: Keep both files/buffers open.